# How do I fix this ImportError that is preventing my code from executing?

Tags: python, flask, importerror

After building a small application with instructions from the Flask tutorial online, I keep getting this ImportError:

```
eloiim:~ iivri.andre$ export FLASK_APP=Minimalapp.py
eloiim:~ iivri.andre$ flask run 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/flask", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 478,in main
    cli.main(args=args, prog_name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 345, in main
    return AppGroup.main(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 696, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1060, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 889, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 534, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 64, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args[1:], **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 534, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 388, in run_command
    app = DispatchingApp(info.load_app, use_eager_loading=eager_loading)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 124, in __init__
    self._load_unlocked()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 148, in _load_unlocked
    self._app = rv = self.loader()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 209, in load_app
    rv = locate_app(self.app_import_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 89, in locate_app
    __import__(module)
 ImportError: No module named Minimalapp.py
```

This is my code:

```
from flask import Flask 
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/') 
def IsSelf() :
    return 'Hello 这是自'
```

HERE is my ls -R output also

```
eloiim:learnFlasC iivri.andre$ ls
Hello.py        Minimalapp.py
Http.py         resource_locator.py
```

I am not sure what I did wrong. What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: It would be helpful if you also included `ls` output showing that `Minimalapp.py`, with that exact name, exists in the current directory. (It's also... surprising... that the Flask documentation tells you to include the `.py` extension in `FLASK_APP`, but then calls `__import__` with it, since that takes a *module* name rather than a *file* name, which implies that the `.py` extension shouldn't be present; if your filename is `Minimalapp.py`, then the module name would be `Minimalapp`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy 

`eloiim:learnFlasC iivri.andre$ ls`

`Hello.py`  `Minimalapp.py`
`Http.py`   `resource_locator.py` 

THIS is the ls output. Ignore the other files

Comment: I suggest that running flask by "flask.run()" in your code to get more information, though it is not a good practice.

Comment: @KirChou So insert `flask.run` after `return 'Hello 这是自'` in my code?

Comment: They probably mean app.run(). Try the steps in the answer I just posted, since you're running into a weird import error that means that it probably won't do anything even with app.run() at the end.

Comment: @T.Arboreus Ok. It worked but there is another issue. I created a templates folder and placed my `index.html` file in it. Though I wrote the render_template('index.html') it in. When I ran it I got `TemplateNotFound: index.html`. WHAT am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to start new questions for stuff like this but the short answer is that you need to create an app folder inside your project folder and put the templates folder inside that. So it should be project folder > app > templates.

Comment: @T.Arboreus Ok. Well stack overflow  banned me from asking questions for awhile so that is why I have to be doing this. I do not know WHAT I am doing wrong. I have been asking questions in the best way I KNOW, reading the help section to improve my question formats, but it's not working.

Comment: You can send me an email every now and then if you get stuck. It's in my profile. SO is what it is, it's a community built around asking tough questions and giving efficient answers. It's not a community for beginners. You will ultimately need to a) find a patient mentor who you can trust b) spend a lot of time on your own figuring things out and getting a lot of errors or c) go on IRC and find a beginner's advice room for your language or problem domain and hang out there. Honestly most SO people did b, which is why they're so crabby with newcomers. Good luck! And accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**To use the FLask cli**

In the command line, navigate to the folder with your project and run:

```
export FLASK_APP=hello.py
flask run
```

Note you need the ".py". The name of the application run script should be the script with the code in it. In the tutorial that's hello.py, but yours might be called MinimalApp.py or similar. You will need to have a new Flask version, 0.11 or higher, as this cli is a new feature.

**Use app.run() instead of the new Flask cli**

First, get rid of all the stuff in your folder or start a new folder. Next, make sure that you can run

```
import flask
```

in the Python REPL without any errors (type "python" in the terminal to access the REPL). Create a file called run.py and paste the following into it:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/') 
def IsSelf() :
    return 'Hello 这是自'

app.run()
```

Save it. In your terminal, navigate to the folder containing the file and run

```
python run.py
```

Comment: What is `REPL`?

Comment: In the command line type "python". You will see >>>. That is the REPL.

Comment: @T.Arboreus It did work. Thank you. Question : I am doing the tutorial on flask and followed the instructions on how to run the program ; `$export FLASK_APP=Minimalapp.py`, `flask run` Yet I got the error I posted before. WHY is that the case?

Comment: When you build bigger applications you create a folder that holds all the stuff relating to your application. By default the folder is called "app" and it sits inside your project folder. I *think* changing that variable changes the name of that folder. Don't bother with it, when you create a bigger application just call your folder app. For now, just put your application into one script. When you want to make a bigger application follow this tutorial:  https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

Comment: Also please accept my answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I do NOT think this is a solution for OP's question. You should explain the error message and how to solve them, not just giving an alternative and not good practice. Note: the official document suggest that using flask CLI rather than hardcode run() inside app.

Comment: +1 I think that's actually fair, though for a learner I think getting it up and running is the important thing. For posterity I've updated my answer to get flask run working. The OP was leaving off the .py in the export FLASK_APP=hello.py. The cli seems like a pretty fresh feature and not rock solid yet, but definitely a great addition.